# Weird behaviour when working on a Java project on a different computer

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I'm working on a Java project in Eclipse. In my home computer where I usually work, it works fine.

But when I imported the project to Eclipse on a different computer, there was some very weird behaviour.

For example (this is a drawing program) - The width of the border surrounding the drawing area is different than on my home computer.

Another example: The user using the 'selection tool', is supposed to draw a dadshed-line rectangle on the screen, until the mouse is released (the rectangle marks the selected area).

In my home computer, it does exactly this. But in the new computer, for some reason the entire border of the drawing area is also changed to dashed when using the selection tool. Very, very weird behaviour.

My question is: **What could cause this weird behaviour when running the project in the same IDE, on a different computer?** Can you give me some advice and guidelines on how to prevent this in the future?

Thanks

Comment: It could be different look&feel. Try to set it manually and compare http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html And for the width... Are you setting it somewhere?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I'm already setting the look&feel manually to the system look and feel. On both computers it should be the same look and feel, they're both Windows 7. And regarding the width of the border. I'm calling `BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.Black, 1)`. So yes, I'm setting it specifically. And this still doesn't explain the really weird behavior with how the border changes to a dashed border when using the selection tool (again, this *doesn't* happen on my usual computer).

Comment: Did you try running it outside IDE? Same JDK?